# How to select rows with specific string from a column with the type of list Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python dataframe df with several columns in it. and I want to select rows with specif string from a column names A, and the data type in each cell of A is ['str1','str2','str3'...]. I used df['A'].str.contains('str2')] but it doesn't work. I don't know where is the problem. Should I convert list type to string before I can do filter?

example:

dataframe:

```
           A                           B       C       D 
  1  [animal,tools,new]               white   nyc      25   
  2  [Italian,restaurant,food]        black   boston   20
  3  [Italian,animal,place]           red     chicago   5
  4  [sky,temp,something]             red     island   90
```

I wanna choose the rows that only contain 'animal' in column A
ideal output:

```
           A                           B       C       D 
  1  [animal,tools,new]               white   nyc      25
  2  [Italian,animal,place]           red     chicago   5
```

Comment: Can you add sample input and output!! That will be helpful

Comment: `df['A'].isin(['str1', 'str2', ...])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can using `in`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[['str1','str2','str3'],['str1']]})
['str2' in x for x in df.A]
Out[28]: [True, False]
```

Comment: thanks! but I want a dataframe as the output, something likes I filtered out the rows with out "animal", only keep the rows that have this word in column A

Comment: @Leran newdf=df[['str2' in x for x in df.A]]

Comment: Thanks it worked! df_business_filtered = df_business_filtered[['animals' in x for x in df_business_filtered['A']]]